# Get the count of rows of a DataTable using Linq or without using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have developed a windows C# application. Used the following data table in my code.

```
DataTable dtManagerSummary = new DataTable();
dtManagerSummary.Columns.Add("Lead Owners", typeof(string));
dtManagerSummary.Columns.Add("Grand Total", typeof(Int32));
dtManagerSummary.Columns.Add("Account", typeof(string));
dtManagerSummary.Columns.Add("RL # Click to update", typeof(string));
dtManagerSummary.Columns.Add("RL Status", typeof(string));
dtManagerSummary.Columns.Add("Aging time", typeof(Int32));
```

My actual result is:

```
Lead Owner | Account name | RL # Click to update | RL Status | Aging Time | Grand Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kavin      | ANU          | RL - 001488727       | RequireFU | 2          | 1
Kavin      | DOD          | RL - 001488734       | RequireFU | 2          | 1
Oviya      | IPA          | RL - 001488736       | RequireFU | 2          | 1  
Thamizh    | NLA          | RL - 001488733       | RequireFU | 2          | 1
Thamizh    | Comcare      | RL - 001488735       | RequireFU | 2          | 1
Thamizh    | AFP          | RL - 001488740       | RequireFU | 2          | 1
```

Expected result:

```
Lead Owner | Account name | RL # Click to update | RL Status | Aging Time | Grand Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kavin      | ANU          | RL - 001488727       | RequireFU | 2          | 2
Kavin      | DOD          | RL - 001488734       | RequireFU | 2          | 2
Oviya      | IPA          | RL - 001488736       | RequireFU | 2          | 1  
Thamizh    | NLA          | RL - 001488733       | RequireFU | 2          | 3
Thamizh    | Comcare      | RL - 001488735       | RequireFU | 2          | 3
Thamizh    | AFP          | RL - 001488740       | RequireFU | 2          | 3
```

From the above example, value in the Grand Total column should be based on the count of Lead Owner column. Here Kavin came for 2 times, Oviya for 1 and Tahmizh is for 3 times.

Note:
Should not group by Lead owner column.

Could anybody help me to achieve the goal?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've shown how you create the table, not how you populate the table.

Comment: See my revised answer for a solution which will allow you to use LINQ in order to accomplish your needs. You can't apply LINQ to `DataTable.Rows` out of the box. But there's a way to work around it.

Comment: Updated again per your revision in title of question.

Answer (score 1):

**With LINQ:**

In order to make use of LINQ, the collection must implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. So the first thing we need to do is to massage the data contained in the [`DataRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class into such. We use the [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in order to accomplish this.

Here is a code example:

```
string leadOwner = "Kavin";
var rows = dtManagerSummary.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
int count = rows.Where(row => (string)row["Lead Owners"] == leadOwner).Count();
```

**Without LINQ:**

You can use the built in support that the `DataTable` class contains. However, rename `"Lead Owners"` to `"LeaderOwners"` or something else that does not have spaces in order for this approach to work.

This uses the [DataTable.Select Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where the `string` argument follows the proper [RowFilter syntax](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

Here is code implementing this approach:

```
string leadOwner = "Kavin";
string expression = String.Format("LeadOwners = '{0}'", leadOwner);
int count = dt.Select(expression).Length;
```

In either approach, the result `count` will be 2 in your case.

Comment: LINQ had a Count() extension method, there is no need to use ToArray

Comment: `Count()` is going to iterate over every item in the collection which is exactly what `ToArray()` is going to do. However, we do have less keystrokes and we're not unnecessarily creating an array - thanks for the critique! :)

Comment: We actually don't need `ToArray()` in the line above either. An `IEnumerable<DataRow>` satisfies our needs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting your DataTable to a List and using Linq to query the list generated.
You should change your Data Tables column names as they do not contain any spaces between words. eg **Lead Owners** should be **Lead_Owners**.

And I create an object which contains your Columns as Fields -

> objResult

```
List<DataRow> list = dtManagerSummary .AsEnumerable().ToList(); 

            var summery = (from d in list 

                           group d by new { d.Lead_Owners,d.Account_name}
                               into g
 select new objResult
                        {
Lead_Owners= (from d in g
               where d.Lead_Owners== g.Lead_Owners
               select d.Lead_Owners
              ).First(),

Account_name= (from d in g
               where d.Lead_Owners== g.Lead_Owners
               select d.Account_name
               ).First(),

RL= (from d in g
               where d.Lead_Owners== g.Lead_Owners
              select d.RL
               ).First(),

RL_Status= (from d in g
             where d.Lead_Owners== g.Lead_Owners 
             select d.RL_Status
              ).First(),

Aging_Time= (from d in g
             where d.Lead_Owners== g.Lead_Owners  
             select d.Aging_Time
             ).First(),
 Grand = g.Sum(S => S.Grand )

}).ToList();
```

This is a simple example to do what required. You must try to apply it to your problem. 
Don't copy and past this as it is. Try and do it your self..